# Play: Accessing static files via URL in tests

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a static xml file in the public folder which I want to access by firing

```
WS.url(myFileUrl)
```

from my tests. Any idea?

Comment: What is your question? Do you get an error?

Comment: are you trying something like this `WS.url(http://localhost:9000/myFileUrl)`?

Comment: @Kris as I figured out the problem was that you have no real server running when you are executing the tests unless you configure one as shown below

Comment: @Todor good you could solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that if you want to access a static file via URL you need to have a real server running and servicing the requests. So you can add the server and specify the port as follows:

```
"run in a server" in new WithServer(port = 3333)) {
     await(WS.url("http://localhost:3333").get).status must equalTo(OK)
    }
```